# In this circuit can the entire bottom row be used for ground?

Tags: ground

[image: Voltage Regulator Circuit]

I have successfully built this voltage regulator but now I need to integrate it into a larger build. Am I correct in thinking that the bottom 3 points can just be treated as the ground plane? Or do I need to have a separate GND that the bottom right seems to indicate? I am just using a 9v battery and downscaling to 5v.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all your GND references can be tied to a ground plane without issue.

The schematic shows a 'separate' (but not really) ground as a reference, which would also show up elsewhere in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The ground symbol just marks that part of the circuit as the part you want to consider as Zero volts/Ground, so it would be part of the ground plane.